# heightForRowAtIndexPath called three times

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have created the static rows inside the tableview having one section. After logging the call for the method of **heightForRowAtIndexPath** I have found that it is called three times for single row. 
Please clarify this behaviour.

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` multiple times?  You might be accidentally refreshing the tableView over and over.

Comment: No I havent called reloadData anywhere explicitly.

Comment: And the obvious: you aren't calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` explicitly anywhere, correct? To define spacing, or anything?

Comment: I have basically made a cell having the datePicker in it. So I am setting its height zero initially and will increase it later when i want to show the date Picker to for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a break point in this function and view from heriachy that from where it was called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

heightForRowAtIndexPath is called multiple times for each row. In my case it was called 3 times for 900 rows before displaying the tableView (I think for calculating the content size of the whole tableview). For me the solution was implementing `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}`, but heightForRowAtIndexPath is still called multiple times but only for the displayed cells.

Answer (score -2):

heightForRowAtIndexPath is called for every single one of your cells. So if you have three cells it will get called three times.

From apple docs ([TableView Docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:):

> Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more)

In addition you'll see it being called when you start scrolling the tableview since the tableview needs to redraw itself when new cells appear and old cells disappear.

EDIT:
Not sure why my answer got downvoted, please add code or more explicit comments if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: No in my case i have three rows in section and it get called for 9 times for each row. And its while loading. I have printed the row index and gets this output in console 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2.